# Save comments in config.yml with api spigot/bukkit

Tags: api, config, bukkit

I have a `config.yml` file that has some comments like:

```yaml
#Thats the message when someone joins to the server
Message: Hello User
```

But when I save the `config.yml` file and open again it vanishes and can't be saved.

I tried to search some api for this problem but could not find.
I dont want to use

```java
saveDefaultConfig();
```

or

```java
getConfig().options.copydefault(true);
saveConfig();
```

because I dont want to save this trough code. I want to save this with api.

What api should I use?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe that only the comments on the first line will be removed. Could you verify that?

Comment: I tried and All the comments are removed when I press save

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the Spigot API, on my opinion it's the better one

Both API's only support ONE comment in the header section of the config. If you  want to save more than one comment you should code your own YAMLConfiguration

To save this one header you should try

```
getConfig().options().header("Your Comment");
getConfig().options().copyHeader(true)
```

You can seperate the comment with \n into mutliple lines

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't save the comments after i save the file not run the plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can create a config.yml inside your src folder which will be included into the jar. You can set your default values and any comments by editing this file in your IDE. All you have to do in your main class is calling `saveDefaultConfig();` in your `onEnable()`. After that, you can use `getConfig()` to access your configuration.

Comment: As I said in the post I dont want to use that command because it wont work

Answer (score 0):

Thats sadly not possible when using the given Tools!

You need to manually write your own ConfigManager where you can do that!

Here is what I got: https://mega.nz/#!lsIkVYhD!knZr5DBmbvPyJh8ONeNx4pfb7Q0C9yuIp6FHiyJmhBw

It may however have a few bugs :D

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the Yaml API provided with Bukkit will strip comments when it is written to. So you can comment your resource config file but comments are lost when it is saved or re-written by the API.

My preferred Yaml handler is [SimplixStorage](https://github.com/Simplix-Softworks/SimplixStorage). It handles comments well both at the top and anywhere inside a yaml file. I also found [SimpleConfig](https://gist.github.com/Magnum97/65aa169a3073d43b4aa3a3c326eade79) which allows you to add header, add comments (which are not removed on file saves), as well as add to config with your code.